# Multithreading with unknown number of tasks

Tags: multithreading, grails, groovy

I'm implementing a crawler for a website with a growing number of entities. There is no information available how many entities exist and no list of all entities. Every entity can be accessed with an URL like this: `http://www.somewebsite.com/entity_{i}` where `{i}` is the number of the entity, starting with 1 and incrementing by 1.

To crawle every entity I'm running a loop which checks if a HTTP requests returns a `200` or `404`. If I get a `404 NOT FOUND`, the loop stops and I'm sure I have all entities.

The serial way looks like this:

```
def atTheEnd = false
def i = 0
while(!atTheEnd){
    atTheEnd = !crawleWebsite("http://www.somewebsite.com/entity_" + i)
    i++
}
```

`crawleWebsite()` returns true if it succeed and false if it got an `404 NOT FOUND` error.

The problem is crawling those entities can take very long that's why I want to do it in multiple threads but I don't know the total amount of entities so every task isn't independent from the other tasks.

Whats the best way to solve this problem?

My approach would be this: Using binary search with REST HEAD requests to get the total number of entities (between 500 and 1000) and split those to some threads.

Is there maybe a better way doing this?

**tl;dr**

Basically I want to tell a threadpool to programmatically create new tasks until a condition is satisfied (when the first `404` occured) and to wait until every task has finished.

Note: I'm implementing this code using `Grails 3`.

Comment: The gpars memoize example seems to do what you are doing? http://gpars.org/1.1.0/guide/guide/single.html#dataParallelism_parallelCollections_memoize

Comment: No, as far as I understood it it does something different. I'm crawling always a new page for every entity, memoize caches a page for further usage. Caching won't help me because every entity is on a different page.

Comment: Could you do basically the same thing but without the memoize?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know how I should do it using `GPars`. How can I tell `GPars` to stop creating tasks when I got the `404`?
Could you please provide me some lines of code what do you mean (don't has to be real working code!)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the total number of entities is not known and can go into thousands. In this case I would simply go for a fixed thread pool and speculatively query URLs even though you may have already reached the end. Consider this example.

```
@Grab(group = 'org.codehaus.gpars', module = 'gpars', version = '1.2.1')
import groovyx.gpars.GParsPool

//crawling simulation - ignore :-)
def crawleWebsite(url) {
    println "$url:${Thread.currentThread().name}"
    Thread.sleep (1)
    Math.random() * 1000 < 950
}

final Integer step = 50
Boolean atTheEnd = false
Integer i = 0
while (true) {
    GParsPool.withPool(step) {
        (i..(i + step)).eachParallel{atTheEnd = atTheEnd || !crawleWebsite("http://www.somewebsite.com/entity_" + it)}
      }
      if (atTheEnd) {
          break
      }
      i += step
}
```

The threadpool is set to 50 and once all 50 URLs are crawled we check if we reached the end. If not we carry on.

Obviously in the worst case scenario you can crawl 50 `404`s. But I'm sure you could get away with it :-)

Comment: I'll try your solution ASAP. :)